# Pull all URLS out of this string in Ruby with scan method

Tags: ruby, regex

I have searched far and wide but cannot find an answer that works. Please test out any links or "already answered here" responses. I have been looking for 3 hours.

Here is my string. Pull out all 6 URLS even if http(s) is not there.

"This string has some urls.For example it has Google.com and Google.com/stuff and then you can see Joe.mysite.co and http://pete.com these are all things that should be detected like https://wtf.net or http://mystuff.com/apathe/433"

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please try writing some code first.

Comment: I did. Has anyone ever pulled out all URLS out of an arbitrary string?

Comment: Yes. There are regexs that match urls. You might have written some code, but you haven't shown any of it to us. Please put up some of the code that you've written so far so we can look at it.

Comment: "Yes. There are regexs that match urls." yet nobody can give an example. I've seen them on here. They don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Twitter text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/rb) for extracting url's

Comment: This is the best way to do it. The gem documentation is lacking but this will take all URLS out once you install the gem. `Twitter::Extractor.extract_urls_with_indices(content)` or use this for just the URLS `Twitter::Extractor.extract_urls(content)`

Comment: Here is file with all the def's for what I am trying to do https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/rb/lib/twitter-text/extractor.rb

Comment: UPDATE: So Twitter Text is pretty useful. The issue I am having with it however is when you create a post. Then transform into link, then edit and re-edit... it really makes a mess of things. I am using  rinku gem now. It is not ideal. It won't find links that don't have http. But my users will just have to realize they need a correct url. This is not a simple problem to solve

Answer (score 1):

Given `s` your string

```
s.scan(/((http(s)?:\/\/)?(\w*\.){0,1}(\w)+\.(co(m)?|net)+(\/(\w)*)*)/).map(&:first)
 => ["Google.com", "Google.com/stuff", "Joe.mysite.co", "http://pete.com", "https://wtf.net", "http://mystuff.com/apathe/433"]
```

Comment: Let me check this one. I wish it was more generic for any valid URL. The example string I have is just an example.

Comment: This is pretty darn good. But not generic. Got a generic one for all top level domains?

Comment: well but how? should I insert all the possibilities? I mean, for me google.com and foo.bar are the same otherwise.